# How can I make an list from existing data frame, each object in a list contains a vector of a single or multiple row from the data frame?

Tags: r

I am very new to R, still getting my head around so my question can be very basic but please help me out!
I have a large data frame, with more than 400000 rows.

```
GENE_ID    p1   p2   p3 ...
41         1    2    3
41         4    5    6
41         7    8    9
85         1    2    3
1923       1    2    3
1923       4    5    6
```

First, I wanted to simply name the GENE_ID as the row name, but due to some gene IDs not unique, I failed.
Now I am thinking of making this data frame into a list each object contains expression level of a gene.
So what I want is a list that has outcome something like,

```
mylist$41
[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

mylist$85
[1] 1  2  3

mylist$1923
[1] 1  2  3  4  5  6
```

Any advice to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `split(unlist(df[-1], use.names = FALSE), df[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `melt` by 'GENE_ID' and then do the `split` to get a `list` of `vector`s

```
library(reshape2)
mylist <- melt(df1, id.var = 'GENE_ID')
split(mylist$value, mylist$GENE_ID)
#$`41`
#[1] 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 6 9

#$`85`
#[1] 1 2 3

#$`1923`
#[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

---

Also, we can do this in `base R`

```
v1 <- unlist(df1[-1], use.names = FALSE)
grp <- rep(df1[,1], ncol(df1[-1]))
split(v1, grp)
```